# Showing an ideal $(x_1, ... ,x_n)$ of a PID $R$ contains 1 using a submodule of $R^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, principal-ideal-domains

This question is from an old comprehensive exam:

Let $R$ be a PID and let $F$ be a free module with basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$. Fix $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in R$, not all zero, and consider the submodule $M$ spanned by $b := x_1e_1 + \ldots + x_n e_n$. Assume that $F = M \oplus N$ for some submodule $N$. Prove that the ideal $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is equal to $R$.

My idea is: write $I = (a)$, $x_i = k_i a$ and consider the module $K$ generated by $k_1e_1 + \ldots + k_ne_n$; then $F = aK \oplus N$. I'd like to use $aK \leq K \leq F$ to conclude that $aK = K$, in which case $a \in R^\times$ is a unit so $(a) = R$. However, I'm not sure how to justify this.

Comment: You are almost there. Let $c = k_1e_1 + \ldots + k_n e_n$. Because $F = M \oplus N$ and $M$ is spanned by $b$, $(c, 0) = (rb, n)$ for some $r \in R$ and $n \in N$. But $b = ac$, so we'd have $c = rb = (ar)c$ and that isn't possible in a free module over an integral domain, unless $ar = 1$ or $b = c = 0$. But we have $b \neq 0$, so $a$ is a unit and $I = R$.

Comment: Or: $N$ is free, so $b$ can be completed to a basis of $F.$ The determinant of the matrix of change of basis is then a multiple of $a,$ which is therefore a unit.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Rob and Anne in the comments:

Let $c := k_1 e_1 + \ldots + k_n e_n$. Since $F = M \oplus N$ and $M$ is spanned by $b$, we can write $c = rb + n$ for some $r \in R$ and $n \in N$.

Suppose $n \neq 0$; then $n \in K$ since $rb \in K$, so $an \in M = aK$. Since $N$ is free, $an \neq 0$ and $an \in M \cap N$, contradicting $F = M \oplus N$. Thus, $n = 0$ and $c = rb$.

Since $b = ac$, we have $c = (ra)c$. Since $M$ is free, we must have $1 = ra$ as $b, c \neq 0$. Thus, $a \in R^\times$ is a unit and $(a) = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) = R$.